# NSScanner not scanning long numeric string into number

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsscanner

I have a string "999999999999528106" and I am passing it to NSScanner but the output is not correct. I get 2147483647 as result.

I guess the big size of my string is not fitting into the NSInteger. Any clue

```
    NSScanner *aScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:iString];
    NSMutableCharacterSet *aCharset = [NSMutableCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet];
    [aCharset formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet]];
    [aScanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:[aCharset copy]];


    NSInteger anIntegerResult = 0;
    [aScanner setScanLocation:0];
    if ([aScanner scanInteger:&anIntegerResult] && aScanner.isAtEnd)
        return @(anIntegerResult);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the `NSScanner` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Skips past excess digits in the case of overflow, so the receiver’s position is past the entire integer representation.

So yes, it's overflowing.  You can use `scanLongLong:` instead.